# Linux PID namespaces

Tags: linux, namespace

I have a question about number of PIDs a process has in context of Linux PID namespaces.

Suppose: (NS = namespace)

P1 (PID NS1) -> clone -> P2 (PID NS2) -> clone -> P3 (PID NS3)

How many PIDs does P3 have ?

I think the following, but I'm not sure if its correct :

- one for NS3
- one for host
- one for NS2
- one for NS1

Thanks.

Comment: What's the purpose of the question?

Comment: Trying to confirm the answer, I'm not sure if 4 is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition of a PID namespace, a process that exists in a namespace has a PID in that namespace, and a (different, except for coincidences) PID in each ancestor namespace. So a process in NS3 has 4 different PIDs: one in NS3, one in NS2, one in NS1, and one in the root namespace.

There is a good [series of posts by Michael Kerrisk about namespaces on LWN](https://lwn.net/Articles/531114/#series_index) — read in particular [Part 3: PID namespaces](https://lwn.net/Articles/532271/) and [Part 4: more on PID namespaces](https://lwn.net/Articles/532748/).